# Essential.Diagnostics TraceEvent with data

Tags: c#, .net, logging, system.diagnostics

I am using Essential.Diagnostics library for logging and it works well. I have set up a SqlDatabaseTraceListener and after running the install sql script coming with the library, I can log activity in the database.

My question :
There is a `Data` field in the logging table, and the `diagnostics_Trace_AddEntry` stored procedure has a `@Data` parameter.

How can I use the [TraceEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.tracesource.traceevent) functionality for adding Data with the logging operation?

Thanks

Comment: What about [TraceData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/44wcw6x8(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

[TraceData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/44wcw6x8(v=vs.110).aspx) does the job.

thanks fretje